# ORACLE QUERY with ROWNUM

Tags: sql, oracle, database, rownum

I am expecting the value to be listed from 1 to 899 for the following query.  But it returns only the value from 1 to 667.  Can somebody help me to find the reason

```
select rownum from all_tables where rownum <900
```

Comment: Maybe because you have only 667 tables?

Comment: Are you sure that you have 900 rows in this table? Try `select rownum from all_tables`?

Answer (score 2):

You have less than 899 tables.

Comment: The author asked how come it returns only 667 rows - this is exactly why, because there are less tables than he expected.

Comment: it's a reasonable guess I suppose.  if you provide some more explanation around exactly why this is THE answer it would help your answer.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest row generator that would not come up short due to lack of rows in your source table / view is:

```
select rownum from dual connect by level < 900;
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
select level as rnum
from dual
connect by level < 900;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select rownum from all_objects where rownum <900
```